# Does Inverting Op Amp Require Buffer at Output to Prevent Influence from Load

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, analog

If the final stage of an op amp cascade is an inverting op amp, should its output be sent through a buffer, or can a load be attached directly to the output of the inverting op amp without fear of undesirable effects?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An ideal opamp has zero output impedance and infinite drive capabiilty, so will not be affected by any following load.

"Real" opamps have finite output impedance and drive.
ANY load will affect them somewhat, no matter how small.
But if the circuit is designed to allow for the non idealities, which is a fundamental part of the design process, then in many cases no buffer is required.

In cases of significant load which cause obvious and undesirable effects a buffer may be a good solution - noting that adding one has its own effects which need to be taken account of.

An opamp in a non inverting circuit may also suffer load effects which make a buffer useful.

Comment: Aside from cost/board real estate, what impact would an unnecessary voltage follower/buffer have on a circuit?

Comment: There will be more, but, off the cuff: additional offset voltage and current, possible stability issues at unity gain (depends on opamp and load - many but not all are unity gain stable), slew rate probably no worse than before, some phase effects (usually probably irrelevant), ... . Spehro will give you a better answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

The inverting amplifier has to handle an additional load because of the feedback resistor.

Often that is insignificant, but it’s worth considering, especially if you are using low value feedback resistors because of high frequencies (not an issue with audio) or to minimize Johnson-Nyqquist noise.

Typically the inverting configuration has less distortion than the non-inverting and you’re adding some additional error terms, so usually you don’t need or want an additional buffer.